# support pinnable task pane with angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, outlook-addin

I am right now trying to implement pinnable task pane in Outlook Windows version, which is the only supported platform. After I added `Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync()` into `Office.initialize`. I found a problem with the angular bootstrapping. Should I bootstrap my app again in the itemChanged handler function? Is there any elegant way to do this?

Here i my code now.

```
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.ItemChanged,
            function(eventArgs) {
                // angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["my-addin"]);
                location.reload();
            },
            function(asyncResult) {
                // This is callback for addHandlerAsync. This will be called ONCE when the event is registered.
            }
        );
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["my-addin"]);
    });
    if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) return;
};
```

I am right now using location.reload() for every itemChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

I could not set up the pinnable feature in my Outlook because I do not have the required Windows/Office update yet to see the pinnable feature but on an assumption, this is what you may be looking for:

```
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.ItemChanged,
            function(eventArgs) {
                // angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["my-addin"]);
                //location.reload();
                //inject the '$window' provider in your service/controller  
                $window.location.reload(); 
            },
            function(asyncResult) {
                // This is callback for addHandlerAsync. This will be called ONCE when the event is registered.
            }
        );
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["my-addin"]);
    });
    if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) return;
};
```

NOTE:
**Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync** requires API requirement set v1.5 whereas Outlook 2016 MSI install only supports till v1.4 at the time of posting this answer.